# explanation for activate_plugin function in wordpress core

Tags: plugins, php, core, activation

This function is in plugin.php file in wordpress core. I read the code and didn't get quietly what does it do. Can anyone give some explanation for this function?

Comment: It activates a plugin, as you'd expect, what more do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know the mechanism of it

Comment: I also want to know; it's ambiguous. what's a "silent" activation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest way is to go to [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin)...

> Attempts activation of plugin in a "sandbox" and redirects on success.
>
> A plugin that is already activated will not attempt to be activated
>   again.
>
> The way it works is by setting the redirection to the error before
>   trying to include the plugin file. If the plugin fails, then the
>   redirection will not be overwritten with the success message. Also,
>   the options will not be updated and the activation hook will not be
>   called on plugin error.
>
> It should be noted that in no way the below code will actually prevent
>   errors within the file. The code should not be used elsewhere to
>   replicate the "sandbox", which uses redirection to work.
>
> If any errors are found or text is outputted, then it will be captured
>   to ensure that the success redirection will update the error
>   redirection.

Comment: I read there but i want to know the insider mechanism of it